# Weblogic OSGI Bundles Hot Deployment

Tags: deployment, osgi, weblogic, weblogic12c, osgi-bundle

Can we do a hot deployment of OSGI bundles in weblogic. Currently i am copying the osgi bundles in osgi-lib folder. Instead of this can we deploy the following jars from weblogic console or WSLT.

In apache karaf we can deploy the bundles from command line. I am looking for something similar in weblogic.

Answer (score 1):

You can always install the [Apache Felix Gogo shell] ... This has commands to install bundles and manage them. (See also [OSGi enRoute Gogo page](http://enroute.osgi.org/appnotes/gogo.html).)An alternative is [Apache Felix FileInstall](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-file-install.html). This allows you to designate a folder and configuration + bundles are automatically synchronized with this folder.